# Best practice for training ML model using data from cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get into google cloud computing but the number of services are just daunting to follow. What I want to do is to

1. load data from a Google Cloud Storage bucket
2. do some things with it (pre-processing)
3. train a model I wrote with the data
4. see if it works well; if not, start again

I am currently trying Google Compute Engine, as the VM is more natural and straight forward. But the probelm I face is that I have to download the data in the bucket locally which seems quite dumb for a "Cloud" service.

I also found out that Vertex AI is a little bit more conjugated with the Google Cloud Storage. But I fear it may be more suitable for pretty data and almost ready model. In my case, I am trying to build a ML model from scratch and would require many trials and debugging.

After hours of digging into a rabbit hole and getting stressed, I thought I am trying to do a ordinary and simple thing and there must be an answer or at least someone must have walked my way.

What would be the best way to write a ML model using data in the cloud storage? Is downloading the data to local storage the best way?

Comment: Are you aware that you can mount the contents of a cloud storage bucket to your vm? That gives you all of the benefits without the need to download it first.

Comment: I disagree with @Botje. Indeed, you can mount a bucket with GCSFuse, but GCS fuse is simply a wrapper from system call to API call. You solve the Linux file system access, but not the latency. In term of training, the best is to download the subset of data (suffled or not) that you need for your training loop (usually, one epoch), and then work locally for the best performances. If you don't store the data locally, your training job will be greatly slowed by the CLoud Storage API access.

Comment: Another tips: use a regional bucket and in the same region as your training VM. You minimize the latency, and does not pay for inter region egress traffic

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I tried to answer the question "there should be something simple that I am missing". Whether FUSE makes sense here entirely depends on how the application is written. Many ML projects read the entire dataset into memory once at the start of the program, and I think there the latency will be completely hidden by `gcsfuse`'s prefetching.

Comment: Agree, it depends on how the data are loaded. If it's at the beginning, Fuse is convenient and avoid a Cloud Storage dependency in the code. The trap is to use Fuse as the file were stored locally, at runtime. In that case, it's dramatic!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you for the comment I will try to add local storage to the compute engine and download the subset of data prior.

Comment: @Botje Thank you for the comment. I will also try the FUSE. The only way for me is to try both. Thanks a lot guys